# Is emissivity always equal to absorbtivity in case of any arbitrary body?

Tags: thermodynamics

We get from the Kirchoff's Law that at thermal equilibrium, e=a can be easily proved. But is this result always valid?

Comment: It is valid in thermal equilibrium: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74679/kirchhoff-law-of-thermal-radiation.

Comment: @fermion This seems to be only an approximation? Because perfect mirror does not exist and that is why always the reflected photon is of a longer wavelength than the ingoing photon.